# Cant interact with Elements in electron app using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, testing, electron, selenium-chromedriver

Im trying to runs tests on my Electron App but I cant seem to interact with any of the elements on the page. It actually seems to select the first element and move onto the next set of test but the button hasn't actually been pressed so it just times out.

My driver looks like this:

```
        public static ChromeDriver startDriverTwo() {
        String projectLocation = System.getProperty("user.dir");

        ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions();
        //Enter the path of your Electron app
        opt.setBinary("C:/path/to/app.exe");
        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", projectLocation + "/chromedriver.exe");

        driver = new ChromeDriver(opt);

        return driver;
    }
```

I then launch a url but it doesnt seem to pick up any of the elements on said page. Im using

```
public class PageFactory {
public PageFactory() {
}

public static <T> T initElements(WebDriver driver, Class<T> pageClassToProxy) {
    T page = instantiatePage(driver, pageClassToProxy);
    initElements(driver, page);
    return page;
}
```

and

```
private static void initAllPages() { // Add EACH ONE of the pages to be initiated here, regardless of 
which section they may be coming from, otherwise a Null Pointer Exception may occur
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, InitPages.class);

}
```

to avoid Null Pointer exceptions

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include an error message and stack trace. We also need a relevant amount of HTML, as well as the Java code that throws the exception.

Comment: Does not it throw an error as 'which section they may be coming from, otherwise a Null Pointer Exception may occur' is not commented out inside a method